# Remove All Sub-Directories and Sub-Files Without Removing Parent/Root Directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, directory

Via Windows Batch, what would the command be to remove all sub directories and sub files of a folder without deleting/removing the said parent/root folder?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
ECHO "Good riddance, cache! Muahahahahahaha"
cd "C:\Users\abrewer\Desktop\cache"
del * /q
```

The above only removes files, but not sub folders. I have also tried RMDIR and RD, those two commands seem to remove the parent/root directory.

Comment: are you limited to windows batch files, or can you use TakeCommand or something similar, with more advanced scripting language?

Comment: I am limited to Windows Batch files... This is for a Windows Server to clear a folder every night or so via a Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way of doing it:

```
cd "C:\Users\abrewer\Desktop\cache"
rd /s /q .
```

It outputs an error message when it tries and fails to delete the parent directory, but otherwise it works perfectly.

Alternatively, something like:

```
cd "C:\Users\abrewer\Desktop\cache"
del * /q
for /D %%i in (*) do rd /s /q "%%i"
```

might work.  Remember to only use single percent signs if you're running from the command line rather than in a batch file.

Comment: +1, very cool the 1st option. I would never have thought to try that. The error message can be hidden by redirection via `2>nul`.

Comment: Nice! I'm using this to clear out the downloads folder on machines without getting rid of the special Download folder with the blue arrow icon

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
ECHO "Good riddance, cache! Muahahahahahaha"
pushd "C:\Users\abrewer\Desktop\cache"
del * /q
for /d %%F in (*) do rd /s /q "%%F"
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "C:\Users\abrewer\Desktop\cache"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
rd /s /q .
```

The first part of the top answer is great but it's also dangerous. Please make sure you have some error checking in your code, as if the directory doesn't exist for some reason you're going to delete what's in your working path.

I'm too new to add a comment and the edit queue was full for the answer to suggest an amendment.